# ESPAsyncWebServerproblema al recibir gran cantidad de datos

Tags: arduino

quiero realizar una conexión entre mi Arduino esp8266 y una aplicacion en Ionic. Lo que estoy haciendo es enviar un Json desde la aplicacion, el cual contiene un array de arrays. Cada array, dentro de ese gran array, contiene los 3 valores ( de 0 a 255 ) en los que se puede representar un color.

Por ejemplo, si tuviese dos leds en la tira, lo que enviaría seria algo como:
{ "array": [[255,0,0],[0,255,0]] }

El problema es cuando se aumenta el numero de leds, en este caso estoy testeando enviando 60 "leds" pero en realidad tengo 144, aunque podrian ser mas en un futuro.
[Codigo Arduino][1]

AsyncWebServer creo que no es capaz de "enviar" tanta cantidad de datos de una sola vez, por lo que lo divide en 3 partes en este caso.

Mi problema es que no se como pasar de uint8_t que es el tipo de los datos que recibo  a char o string. Para asi poder concatenar lo que recibo y pasarlo al parseador de ArduinoJson.
Ejemplo de lo que recibo ahora:

**Primera parte**

{"array":[[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,

**Segunda parte**

128],[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128]],"array2":[[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128],[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128]],"array3":[[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128],[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128]],"array4":[[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128],[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128]],"array5":[[255,0,0],[

**Tercera parte**

0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128],[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,255,0],[0,255,255],[128,128,128]]}

Si a alguien se le ocurre una mejor manera utilizando otras funciones o librerias, seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: debes traducir al español la pregunta o será cerrada. Por otro lado, si no deseas traducirla, puedes proponerla en [Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Actualizado @RogerTorné